# Setting last logged in time with bearer authentication and webapi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I'm using bearer authentication with webapi2 to authenticate against my REST API. I'd like to be able to set the users last logged in time in my User store when they successfully authenticate and get a token back. How would I go about doing this? Is there a hook somewhere for executing code on a successful login?

This is my setup code so far. I have my own implementation of IPasswordHasher

```
    UserManagerFactory = () =>
        {
            var manager = WebApiApplication.NinjectKernel.Get<UserManager<OwinUser>>();
            manager.PasswordHasher = WebApiApplication.NinjectKernel.Get<IPasswordHasher>();
            return manager;
        };

    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this by doing your own implementation of the ApplicationOAuthProvider.

You can see the source code for the one you're using [here](https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet.Identity/blob/master/examples/KriaSoft.AspNet.Identity.DbFirst/Security/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs).

I'm fairly sure you can do this either in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials or the TokenEndpoint methods. You're going to have to step through the code for a couple of requests to determine the best place to do this in. You can then do this by using the userManager like is done in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method.

I think another way would be to implement your own user manager which is a more complicated and time consuming way to do it. I won't get into that since I'm pretty sure you can do it with the method i mentioned above.